# No puedo insertar la dependencia @Transactional en Intelljr

Tags: java, intellij-idea, transacciones, dependencias

El símbolo o la dependencia **@transactional** no quiere ser reconocido por **intelljr**, si le doy a buscar **dependency** en **maven** me la encuentra, pero al agregarla me sale el siguiente error:

[image: Eso es lo que pasa cuando agrego la dependencia]

[image: Y estas son las opciones que me salen]

Este es mi archivo pom:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
            <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
        </parent>
        <groupId>com.cursoJava</groupId>
        <artifactId>curso</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <packaging>war</packaging>
        <name>curso</name>
        <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
        <properties>
            <java.version>19</java.version>
        </properties>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            </dependency>
    
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.cursoJava</groupId>
                <artifactId>curso</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.mageddo.tobby-transactional-outbox</groupId>
                <artifactId>tobby-transactional-outbox</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.1</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    
    </project>
```

Aca es donde lo quiero agregar, es un DaoImp (java):

```
    package com.cursoJava.curso.dao;
    
    import com.cursoJava.curso.Models.Usuario;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
    import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
    
    import java.util.List;
    
    @Repository
    @Transactional
    
    public class UsuarioDaoImp implements usuarioDao{
    
        @Override
        public List<Usuario> getUsuarios() {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Muchas gracias de antemano, el **import** lo puse a mano para ver si podia forzarlo a andar pero no fue el caso xd.

Comment: Dale a Build. O en la pesnaña Maven, dale a refrescar para que recargue las dependencias que no se han descargado localmente en `~/.m2/repository`

Comment: No me a funcionado :(

Answer (score 0):

Para poder importar `@Transactional` de springframework, tenés que cambiar las importaciones en el POM.
Estás importando

```
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.mageddo.tobby-transactional-outbox</groupId>
                <artifactId>tobby-transactional-outbox</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.1</version>
            </dependency>
```

que es una biblioteca que surge de este [proyecto](https://github.com/mageddo-projects/tobby-transactional-outbox). Además la versión que estás importando tiene problemas de seguridad varios como podés ver [acá](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.mageddo.tobby-transactional-outbox/tobby-transactional-outbox/1.5.1).

En su lugar te sugiero reemplazar lo anterior con:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Además, veo que estás usando la versión 3 de Spring Boot. En esta versión migraron todas las Java EE api a sus equivalentes en Jakarta. Tal vez te convenga replantear el proyecto con la última versión disponible de Spring Boot 2. En el siguiente [enlace](https://spring.io/blog/2022/01/20/spring-boot-3-0-0-m1-is-now-available) podés leer más sobre la nueva versión de Spring Boot.
Para esto tendrías que reemplazar en el POM la versión 3 por la última versión disponible de Spring Boot 2.

```
<version>2.7.9</version>
```

y hacer un rebuild del proyecto Maven.

Answer (score 0):

Solución IntelliJ :

Para aquellos que enfrentan este problema en IntelliJ, es posible que solo necesiten volver a cargar el proyecto. En su archivo POM.xml, haga clic derecho en cualquier lugar y vaya a Maven->"Recargar proyecto".[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]